# How to put a folder which has large files (.avi and .pdf) as well as source files (.py, .m) in multiple directories under git source control?

Tags: git, version-control

I have a large folder of ~ 4 GB. This folder has python source code, Matlab source code, a lot ~50-80 MB video files as well as pdf files. I was originally planning to put them all under .git source control and put them in github, but I found that it made everything really slow. Further, github started complaining that I am using too much of their bandwidth.

I am thinking that a better approach would be to keep the .avi or other large files in the similar structure, but to only put the source files under git control by adding the lines

```
*.avi
*.pdf
*.mp4
!*.py
!*.m
```

The above line will not put .avi, .pdf and .mp4 files under source control, but always put .py and .m files under source control.

The .pdf, .mp4 files are important, but I just don’t want to upload to github. I would also want to change or checkout differenct branches of the repository at certain times in future.

## Questions

1. Say I have a folder now called videos under a certain subdirectory such as

Videos/
         Oop.avi

Say the previous version of the folder doesn’t have this. **Will the Videos directory be completely overwritten if I checkout the previous branch?**

I am sure there will be other permutations and combinations of the above scenario which might happen.

2. **What is the best practice for such cases, when the large files are mixed in with source files in various directories?** But you don’t want to necessarily share the large files, but don’t want to lose them either, if you checkout a previous branch which didn’t have the large files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The .pdf, .mp4 files are important, but I just don’t want to upload to
>   github. I would also want to change or checkout differenct branches of
>   the repository at certain times in future.

So you do not want to manage these kinds of files `.pdf`, `.mp4` and `.avi` in git repo, but want the files show in your local git repo across the versions and branches.

**`.gitignore`** does meets your requirements. You can add the below lines in .gitignore file:

```
**/*.avi
**/*.pdf
**/*.mp4
```

So the `.avi`, `.pdf` and `.mp4` files will be ignored by git repo no matter which subdirectories will the files be added. And these files and directories will also be showed when you checkout to a different branches or versions.

Answer (score 1):

Files that match a gitignore pattern are ignored by git: it won't touch them. So ignored files won't be deleted. (BTW, it's also the case for any untracked files, ignored ones will just be not visible in `git status`)

The only way to delete ignored files through git is with [`git clean -x`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean)

Comment: @zingarn, thanks for replying.

 I understand that files which are in .gitignore are not added to the source control, as I mentioned above.

 what do you mean by git wont _touch_ them?

Comment: If git doesnt touch ignored files, isnt a simple `rm` equivalent to using `git clean -x`?

Comment: Git won't delete ignored files. You can of course delete them with a simple `rm`, `git clean -x` is the only way **for git** to delete them.